# Can't solve this equation involving the natural logarithm

Tags: logarithms

> Solve for $y$: $\frac12\ln(\sqrt{2y+1})) = \ln(3) + \ln(y-1)$.

I got to $\sqrt{2y+1} = (y+2)^2$, but then don't know where to go from here

I've now got to $(\sqrt{2y+1})^\frac{1}{2} = 3y-3$

Comment: $$(2y-1)=\{3(y-1)\}^4$$

Comment: Sum of logs is log of product: $\ln(3) + \ln(y-1)=\ln(3y-3)$

Comment: Why $ (y+2)^2$?

Comment: I put the 1/2 at the top of the ln expression and cancelled all ln . Then I got rid of the half by squaring both sides

Comment: $\ln 3+\ln (y-1)$ is $\ln[3(y-1)]$, not $\ln[3+(y-1)]$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee:  did you mean $2y\color{red}+1$ ?

Comment: The answer isn't very neat, are you sure this is the equation given?

Comment: KM101 Yea that is the equation

Comment: I am already surprised that they ask the students to solve a fourth order polynomial equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got $$\ln(\sqrt{2y+1})=\ln(9)+\ln((y-1)^2)$$ so $$\sqrt{2y+1}=9(y-1)^2$$
Then we get $$2y+1=(3(y-1))^4$$ and this is $$81 y^4-324 y^3+486 y^2-326 y+80=0$$
The Solutions don't look nice:
$$\left\{1+\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2
   \left(1+\sqrt{1297}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{2\
   6^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{1297}}}}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2
   \left(1+\sqrt{1297}\right)}}{9\ 3^{2/3}}+\frac{2\ 2^{2/3}}{3 \sqrt[3]{3
   \left(1+\sqrt{1297}\right)}}+\frac{4}{27 \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2
   \left(1+\sqrt{1297}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{2\
   6^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{1297}}}}}}\right\}$$

Comment: With these solutions: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2y%2B1+%3D+(3(y-1))%5E4

Comment: LOL this has to be a joke, surely not for a school question...

Comment: Maybe, you have made a typo!

Comment: @Newbie101 No, because $(3y)^4=3^4y^4=81y^4$.

Comment: Yea i figured, I don't know why we were given this question...

Comment: It must be a typo